# xcode9 requires a provisioning profile

Tags: ios, jenkins-plugins, xcode9, xcodebuild, xcode-plugin

I am using xcode plugin (version 2.0.1) with jenkins to generate our builds for multiple targeted app.

With Xcode 9, our jenkins build configuration is able to generate the archive but fails to create the ipa. The error message is as follows:

> `Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 ""test.app" requires a provisioning profile." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription="test.app" requires a provisioning profile., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to the "provisioningProfiles" dictionary in your Export Options property list.}`

I have already added the provisioning profile inside Jenkins **Custom xcodebuild arguments** section by passing the PROVISIONING_PROFILE, PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER, CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY, CODE_SIGN_STYLE and DEVELOPMENT_TEAM however, it still shoots the same error message. Besides, I also pass the ExportOptions.plist file in the Build phases Run script option but it seems that Xcode generates its own ExportOptions.plist(**enterpriseTEAMIDExport.plist**) and ignores mine. When I open enterpriseTEAMIDExport.plist file it only contains the teamid and the method of export and so, it doesn't find the provisioning profile.

So, how can I tell xcode to use my ExportOptions.plist file instead? I have followed the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkqkG.png) but unable to find it inside Xcode 9. Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46723773/assertion-exportarchive-test-app-requires-a-provisioning-profile) post doesn't relate to me.

Another important thing is that I am able to generate the ipa using my own ExportOptions.plist file from command line xcodebuild tool using this command as follows:

`xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath archive.xcarchive -exportPath /my/export/path -exportOptionsPlist options.plist`

So, I don't know why it doesn't work with Jenkins Xcode plugin.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hé Ron, any luck getting this working again?

Comment: @RoolPaap Sorry man.... hard on luck with this one. I will keep you posted if I get any solution.

Comment: I reverted back to version 1.4.11 and added the PackageApplication from a previous version (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43935071/443270) and removed the resource-rules part of it (https://stackoverflow.com/a/26674605/443270)

Comment: Did it work then?

Comment: @RoolPaap Just in case if it helps .. Check this issue created on jenkins
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45509

Comment: The same is happening with me when running `cordova build ios --release --device` which creates release IPA.

Comment: Check out my answer in another post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53477529/2000405